# How can I show my custom css on the iPhone 5 web app?

Tags: html, iphone, css, web-applications

I am using bootstrap as a framework to create iPhone app. I am only using the css styles. However, when I add this to the page:

```
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

On my iPhone web app that I have saved to the home screen, it does not show my custom css that I changed in the bootstrap.min.css.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [Apple docs: Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html). You can determine if full-screen mode is on by using window.navigator.standalone. If the bool is false, you know where the problem is.